# angular 11 form dynamic data binding

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have a form inside which I a pair of inputs, one for a name and one for a number. The number of such pairs needed depends on a user input, e.g. if users enter 5, it will generate 5 such pairs. So far, I can get the UI part working, e.g. it can dynamically generate needed pairs. The problem is data binding for those dynamically generated input pairs. Because they are part of a form, I can't use `[(ngModel)]`. I tried to use `FormControlName` but it doesn't work due to the dynamic nature of each input pair; it seems that each `FormControl` has to be created when the components initialized. Other controls in the form are not shown.
I have a feeling that maybe I approach this in the wrong way, is there an 'angular' way of doing this?

```
<form [formGroup]="projectForm">
        <div>
            Enter the number of jobs：<input type="number" formControlName="jobCounter2"><br>
            <ng-container *ngFor="let i of [].constructor(projectForm.value.jobCounter2); let j = index">
                <div>
                    <ng-container style="width: 2px;">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="job name" formControlName="jobNames2[j]">
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container style="width: 1px">
                        <input type="number" placeholder="job salary e.g. 3.4" formControlName="jobSalary2[j]">
                    </ng-container>
                </div>
            </ng-container>
        </div> 
    </form>
```

Comment: Can you try rxforms from ```@rxweb/reactive-form-validators```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach can be improved for a better user experience, consider this

1. Same as your approach, a user can add more fields but do not bind this value to the form
2. Include a <kbd>Delete</kbd> button

This is how your TS File will look like

```typescript
  projectForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    jobs: this.formBuilder.array([])
  });

  get jobs() {
    return this.projectForm.get("jobs") as FormArray;
  }
  deleteJobField(i) {
    this.jobs.controls.splice(i, 1);
    this.jobs.updateValueAndValidity()
  }
  addJobField($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    console.log( Array(this.additionalJobFields))
    Array(this.additionalJobFields).fill(1).forEach(() => {
      this.jobs.push(
        this.formBuilder.group({
          name: "",
          salary: 0
        })
      );
    });
    this.additionalJobFields = null;
  }
  additionalJobFields = null;
```

And in your html

```html
<form [formGroup]="projectForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div>
        <ng-container formArrayName="jobs">
            <div *ngFor="let job of jobs.controls; let j = index" [formGroupName]="j">>
                <ng-container style="width: 2px;">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="job name" formControlName="name">
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container style="width: 1px">
                        <input type="number" placeholder="job salary e.g. 3.4" formControlName="salary">

            <button (click)='deleteJobField(j)' type="button">DEL</button>
                    </ng-container>
            </div>
        </ng-container>

    <button>Show Values</button>
    </div>
        Add More Jobs：<input type="number" (keydown.enter)="addJobField($event)" [(ngModel)]="additionalJobFields"  [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"><br>
</form>
<pre>{{ projectForm.value | json }}</pre>
```

The basic idea is that when a user enters a value in the input field for adding more jobs and presses enter, we update the number of fields in the form array.

We also add a delete button against each input category and update form array when this is clicked

[See this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tzi3wh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: thanks for this but I just checked the demo; it doesn't seem to add any inputs at all when I increase the job counter input. Am I missing something?

Comment: You enter a number and press enter, I believe that is how most users expect

Comment: oh I see. Pressing enter may not fit with mobile phones? And it seems that it's accumulating the counter; e.g. if I enter 3 first, then change it to 2; it adds another 2 rows. But should be easy to adjust I guess.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dztmps?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Check out the above modification, I believe it works as you have described but for me I would not go for this

Comment: Hi Owen, just had a quick check about version2 and it seems exactly what I needed. I wouldn't want pressing Enter to fire increase counter because my app will be mostly viewed on mobile. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`FormArray`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray) to dynamically create controls. Listen to the change event of *JobCounter* element then you can iterate and add `FormControl` to the Jobs array.

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  VERSION
} from "@angular/core";
import {
  Form,
  FormArray,
  FormBuilder,
  FormGroup
} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  projectForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.projectForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      jobCounter: [],
      jobs: this.formBuilder.array([]) //<=== Create Empty array
    });
  }

  onJobCounterChange(value) {
    value = Number(value);

    // Create the desired group based on user input
    for (let i = 0; i < value; i++) {
      let fb = this.formBuilder.group({
        name: [""],
        salary: [""]
      });
      (this.projectForm.controls.jobs as FormArray).push(fb);
    }
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.projectForm.value);
  }
}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="projectForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div>
    Enter the number of jobs：
    <input type="number" formControlName="jobCounter" (change)="onJobCounterChange(projectForm.controls.jobCounter.value)"><br>
    <ng-container formArrayName="jobs">
      <div *ngFor="let job of projectForm.get('jobs')['controls']; let j = index" [formGroupName]="j">>
        <ng-container style="width: 2px;">
          <input type="text" placeholder="job name" formControlName="name">
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container style="width: 1px">
          <input type="number" placeholder="job salary e.g. 3.4" formControlName="salary">
        </ng-container>
      </div>
    </ng-container>

    <button>Show Values</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

[Working Example](https://angular-ivy-i1kt4f.stackblitz.io/), You can also play [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-i1kt4f?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: I am still trying to figure out how this works exactly, but in the example, it seems to always increase the job name and salary inputs even when decreasing the job counter. Also it seems to add two pairs (that's four inputs) when increasing job counter by one.

Comment: @stt106, Above one, is not complete. It just demonstrates the addition of job name and salary inputs based on counter. Do go through  https://netbasal.com/angular-reactive-forms-the-ultimate-guide-to-formarray-3adbe6b0b61a

Comment: @stt106, Here is an alternate approach https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-z1h11d?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html